# C How to remove a character from a string and keep the rest?

Tags: c

I want to remove a character '#' from a string like "#-9" and convert the rest to an integer value. I know how to convert string to integer without the '#', so I tried to delete this using code

```
void delChar(char *str, int x) {
    char *q;
    q = str;
    while(*q == *(q+1)) q++;
    *q='\0';
}
```

But it will terminate the string, so how do I fix this problem.

Comment: If the remainder after the `#` in a string pointed to by some `char *str` is *known* to be integer in question, why bother removing *anything* ?Just convert using `str+1` as the string containing the integer rather than `str` wherever you're doing the conversion.

Comment: Your function never refers to `x`. The condition `(*q == *(q+1))` doesn't match anything in your problem description (and is IMHO more clearly written as `(q[0] == q[1])`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code. Let me know if you didn't understand something.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* delChar(char *str, char replace_char)
{
  char *newStr;
  int i=0, * flag;
  newStr= (char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char)); 
  if (newStr == NULL)
  {
   printf("Out of memory ...!");
   exit(-1);
  }
  while (*str != '\0' )
  {
    if (*str != replace_char)
    {
        newStr[i]= *str;
        ++i;
        flag= realloc(newStr,i*sizeof(char));

        if (flag == NULL)
        {
          printf("Out of memory ...!");
          exit(-1);
        }
    }
      str= str+1; 
  }

 return newStr;
}


int main()
{
    char *str = "#-#9#66#";
    char* newStr;
    newStr= delChar(str, '#');

    printf("%d\n", atoi(newStr)); // use atoi() to convert string to integer

  return 0;
}
```

output:
`-966`